# Symfony3 HWIOauth Bundle can't use/find Google Login-Check route

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony, hwioauthbundle

When running debug:router I get the following error:

```
FileLoaderLoadException
The routing file "/Users/rmason/sandbox/MTI_Products/app/config/routing.yml" contains unsupported keys for "google_login": "pattern". Expected one of: "re
source", "type", "prefix", "path", "host", "schemes", "methods", "defaults", "requirements", "options", "condition" in /Users/rmason/sandbox/MTI_Products/
app/config/routing.yml (which is being imported from "/Users/rmason/sandbox/MTI_Products/app/config/routing_dev.yml").
```

You can find the full relevant code on this gist...
https://gist.github.com/Rick-Mason/a63f968baf4fb828daa34123f3d89724

However I will post some of the code here.
My routing:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile



#hwi_oauth_login:  
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /login

google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google
```

All of the Friends of Symfony User Bundle works. When I comment out the offending code (google_login) above. I get to the login screen and the link to be sent to google. I login with google, but my assumption is that without that route, google can't respond to a known redirect URL

./bin/console config:dump-reference hwi_oauth shows some settings in the resource_owners key, (such as access_token_url and authorization_url) but my assumption on those is so that you can set what api urls you are calling.

Unfortunately I can not find any reference in google or here about this problem.

Here is the relevant services.yml code
parameters:
    my_user_provider.class: HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider

```
services:
    my_user_provider:
        class: '%my_user_provider.class%'
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager',{google: google_id}]
```

and here is the relevant config.yml code:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\MTI_Cart\User

hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [main]

    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            google: google_id

    resource_owners:
        google:
            type:                google
            client_id:           mygoogleclientid
            client_secret:       mygooglesecret
            scope:               "email profile"
```

Comment: I found the answer already, but will leave the code up for others to follow as there is not much out there yet for setting up this common configuration in Symfony 3... I had to change the word "pattern" for the word "path". My guess is that this change was made in the new dev-master bundle for HWIOauth as it is the only one that works at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following Config Lines From:

```
google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google
```

To the following

```
google_login:
    path: /login/check-google
```